# Why would the NAV/share of the same mutual fund be different for different classes?

Tags: mutual-funds

Why would the NAV/share of the same mutual fund be different for different classes?

For example, looking at the fairly popular Fidelity Contrafund Fund, we see...
[image]

Yet looking at the class K shares, we see...

[image]

So they're a bit off.

I though that they are all just buying into the same pool of overall money and that the classes only differed in *the required minimum investment and associated fee structure*. Could someone explain how this happens? What could be going on here?

Answer (score 5):

FCNKX has a lower expense ratio than FCNTX, since FCNKX is only available to retirement and other plans that are managed or affiliated with Fidelity (i.e. it's a benefit they offer in exchange for other services), so the NAV growth has slightly less friction the widely-available fund.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? Again, I thought that they are all just buying into the same pool of overall money and assets (ie. that it's *the same fund no matter what class* of shares you buy, so the NAV in either case should be the same). As I understood it, *NAV calculations do not include any expenses per class*. What am I missing here?